# Django WSGIRequest args error

Tags: python, django, django-wsgi

I'm get this
`AttributeError("'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'args'",)`
when I try and make this call

`GET /sign_s3/?s3_object_type=image/jpeg&s3_object_name=default_name`

Am I missing something?

Do I need to include `*args, **kwargs` in addition to request?

Here's the traceback:

```
            response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
            if response:
                break
    if response is None:
        wrapped_callback = self.make_view_atomic(callback)
        try:
            response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
        except Exception as e:
            # If the view raised an exception, run it through exception
            # middleware, and if the exception middleware returns a
            # response, use that. Otherwise, reraise the exception.
            for middleware_method in self._exception_middleware:
                response = middleware_method(request, e)
```

the view:

```
@login_required()
def sign_s3(request):
    object_name = request.args.get('s3_object_name')
```

Comment: Are we supposed to figure out what's going on without the traceback?

Comment: That's not the traceback, that appears to be some other random code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HttpRequest` object doesn't have `args` attribute.

You should use

```
request.GET.get('s3_object_name')
```

to get `s3_object_name value`.

Django documentation has an excellent [section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest) on `HttpRequest`.

Comment: Yep, that was it! Must remember... documentation first!

Answer (score 0):

HttpRequest object has dictionary-like object id doesn't have args attribute

If key is mandatory and exist in request object you can use:

request.GET['s3_object_name']

> This will return a value of a if key exists.  If not then an Exception
>
> If your keys are optional:

request.GET.get('s3_object_name')

Answer (score 0):

And in the same with this erreur :
except User.DoesNotExist: Attribute Error: 'function' object has no attribute 'DoesNotExist'

```
class UserPosts(generic.ListView):
   model = models.Post
   template_name = 'posts/user_post_list.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    try:
        self.post_user = User.objects.prefetch_related("posts").get(
            username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username")
        )
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    else:
        return self.post_user.posts.all()

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["post_user"] = self.post_user
    return context
```

am solve it by :

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()